# Post json using Xcode

Tags: php, json, post, xcode4, nsmutableurlrequest

I am trying to send data, in json format to my webservice, using POST. I have a php page on my server that receives the json string and prints it out.

The issue is, that the POST array recieved is empty, below is my code on my application:

```
NSString *jsonRequest = @"{\"username\":\"james\",\"password\":\"james1234\"}";
NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[jsonRequest UTF8String] length:[jsonRequest length]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://mydomain.com/check.php"]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:requestData];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:[request autorelease] delegate:self];
```

The check.php has the following code:

```
<?php

    print_r($_POST);
?>
```

I am getting the following output:
        Array(
              )

I have tried everything, and cannot seem to get the json string sent to my webservice. I am sure, I am missing something, however I do not know what it is.

Comment: Try adding the `Content-Length` header...

Comment: I believe, I do have the Content-Length code, it is the last line with starts with [request ...

Comment: You may also want to try with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for the content type.

Comment: And I don't think the `Accept` header is needed...

Comment: Hello Macmade, I did try the application/x-www-from-urlencoded, and unfortunately it did not work for me. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Have you checked the return value of `connectionWithRequest`? It may be nil...

Comment: The return value for connectionWithRequest is:
<NSURLConnection: 0x4c30a60. http://mydomain.com/check.php>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work, I had to use the [ASIHTTP](http://allseeing-i.com) library. below is the code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://mydomain.com/check.php"]];

ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request setPostValue:@"james" forKey:@"username"];
[request setPostValue:@"james1234" forKey:@"password"];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

Comment: forgot the following line of code, right before the startAsynchronous
    [request setPostValue:@"submit" forKey:@"post"];
    [request startAsynchronous];